# Will each use of an angular Controller create a new Instance of if?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created an angular controller `UserController`.

one in my index.html like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" ng-controller="UserController as account">
    <span ng-model="somePropertieInsideMyController"></span>
</nav>
```

and the second time through a `$routeProvider` in app.main.js like this:

```
.when('/login', {
  controller: 'UserController',
  controllerAs: "account",
  templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
})
```

My Question is, after loading the page, do I have two instances of the controller or will there be only ONE controller two which both parts are bound and share the `$scope`?

If there are two instances created, How can I share the properties that may be update inside the controller across both appearances.

Comment: But you can't hit both `index.html` and `login.html` at the same time. So there will never be two instances of `UserController` running at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

> When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller directive, Angular will instantiate a new Controller object, using the specified Controller's constructor function. A new child scope will be created and made available as an injectable parameter to the Controller's constructor function as $scope.

So yes, a new instance of the controller will be created.

To share data between controllers, the most common approach is to use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Answer (score 1):

This way you will have 2 different `$scope`. It's quite strange to use the same controller the way you did. Usually the specific controller is provided by `$routeProvider`, you may consider a sort of global controller in the main page.